# Whats the fastest way of java collection removeAll from two large collections

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have ~6 million records in a mssql (master data)
~6 million records in an elasticsearch

I want to remove records from elasticsearch which do not exist in database.

When I use two ArrayLists in java it is very slow. Also with a TreeMap on the left-hand-side. I have increased a timeout to 10mins, but it wont finish within this period.
Whats a much faster option in java only?

If there is no much faster option it would be possible to make a mssql table for this purpose and let mssql handle the diff operation.

Would it make sense to make an elasticsearch "delete by query" with 6m clauses? Can I increase the much clauses just for only query? Preferably by url query param or in request body?

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in ES would probably be fastest and while the database would be able to do it very fast as well you'd have to send the data over the wire multiple times.

When doing it in Java you'd need to consider the complexity of all the methods and the data structures you're using (since both lists are of comparable size I just assume they have the same size n for simplicity):

**2 Lists with removeAll() or a similarly simple approach**

Using 2 lists (not even talking ArrayLists here) would mean a time complexity of O(n^n).

**TreeMap for the DB data**

Using a TreeMap for the DB data and a list for the ES data would turn that into O(n * log(n))

- O(n * log(n)) for building the TreeMap
- O(n * log(n)) for iterating over the list and checking for values in the TreeMap

However, here's where the list structure also plays a role: removing elements from an ArrayList will cause data to be shifted, even if you iterate backwards. However, you don't really need fast random access to that list so a LinkedList would be better for this.

Also, using a HashMap instead of a TreeMap could improve timing as this basically turns building the map into O(n) and doing lookups into O(n) as well (O(n) for list iteration and O(1) for the lookup if the map is configured with the correct size). It will use more memory and won't allow for duplicates (but neither does TreeMap) though so that would need to be considered.

Example:

```
List<DBRecord> dbRecords = loadFromDB();
List<ESRecord> esRecords = loadFromES();

Map<Key, DBREcord> dbMap = new HashMap<>();
dbRecords.forEach(r -> dbMap.put(r.getKey(), r));

//not needed if esRecords is a LinkedList already and you want to modify it directly
List<ESRecord> resultList = new LinkedList<>(esRecords);
for(Iterator<ESRecord> itr = resultList.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
  ESRecord esRecord = itr.next();
  DBRecord dbRecord = dbMap.get(esRecord.getKey());

  if(dbRecord != null) {
    //found a match so remove it - what's left are the records to remove
    itr.remove();
  }
}
```

**Working with 2 sorted lists**

If you can't use a HashMap you could try using 2 sorted lists and advance them at the same time. If you can get the lists presorted from ES and the DB then this would have O(n) complexity, otherwise you'd need to sort them first which would turn this into O(n * log(n)).

When you have the lists sorted you basically iterate over both of them at the same time, applying the following logic:

- If the elements at the respective current cursor (e.g. iterator or index) are different, advance the cursor of the list with the smaller value
- If the elements are equal you found a match, so remove it from one of the lists or collect it into some result list. Additionally you advance the cursor of both lists.

Example:

```
//Assumption: the lists you get are already sorted and contain at least 1 element
List<DBRecord> dbRecords = loadFromDB();
List<ESRecord> esRecords = loadFromES();

Iterator<DBRecord> dbItr = dbRecords.iterator();
Iterator<ESRecord> esItr = esRecords.iterator();

//get the first elements
DBRecord dbCurrent = dbItr.next();
ESRecord esCurrent = esItr.next();

while( dbItr.hasNext() && esItr.hasNext()) {
  int comparison = dbCurrent.getKey().compareTo(esCurrent.getKey());

  if( comparison < 0) {
    //the db record's key was smaller
    dbCurrent = dbItr.next();
  } else if ( comparison > 0) {
    //the es record's key was smaller - if you collect records to remove, do it here
    esCurrent = esItr.next();
  } else {
    //found a match

    //we're removing matches in this example
    esItr.remove();

    dbCurrent = dbItr.next();
    esCurrent = esItr.next();
  }
}

//when you're here you might not have looked at all es records but those that remain are no matches
//if you're collecting differences, keep using esItr until there are no more records
```

Comment: i have tried hashmap + linkedlist ... which isnt fast enough for me. i guess the temporary table will be fast. since i have multi nodes in production which are triggered by "polling consumer" and REST API ... there is the danger that several jobs conflict over mssql temporary table names

Answer (score 1):

Potential solution:
mssql DB trigger which will put IDs of physical deleted records into a new table + some date.

Then a new job triggered by enterprise integration pattern "polling consumer" + REST API will gather the next 60.000 (default max clauses is 65xxx) IDs from DB and remove them from elasticsearch via delete by query.